# CheckBox.CheckedChanged not fired on winform

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
    }
```

I set the check state in load event handler, and why in this case, the CheckedChanged not fired?
If i click the check box, then the CheckedChanged is fired.

Comment: @danbystrom, yes it is called.

Comment: @Rohit, what's the point of your link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your checked state is initially `false`, then setting it to `false` again doesn't fire the `CheckedChanged` event.
That happens because the checked state isn't actually *changed*

This is the internal code used when trying to set the  `CheckBox1.Checked` property

```
public void set_Checked(bool value)
{
    if (value != this.Checked)
    {
        this.CheckState = value ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked;
    }
}
```

Comment: ...because the checked state isn't actually *changed*. You make it sound like this is a bug.

Comment: @CodyGray yep, added to the answer your observation